# c# webbrowser control select radio button

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to get my webbrowser1 to click/select a radio button and as well click a submit button without any id or name.

Here is the html code from the webpage:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="3" id="a3">
   <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="2" id="a2">
   <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="1" id="a1">
   <input value="Next" type="submit">
</form>
```

and here is the C# code I've tried:

```
wbv(3); //This part just check every 3 seconds to see if the page the page has loaded before continuing with the code
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("chosen")[2].InvokeMember("click");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByValue("Next")[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

I need help to figure out how to get my code to select the radio button with value 3 and then click the submit button.

Comment: hi Patric, let me know if the solution works, or if you need more help. I'm willing to help out :)

Comment: hey Patric, can you mark the solution as  resolved, if it has helped you on this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `wbv(3);` ///This part just check every 3 seconds to see if the page the page has loaded before continuing with the code`

You can use `WebBrowser` control's *DocumentCompleted* event handler to get notified when page has loaded.

This line is used to register this event

```
//When the page has loaded it will make a call to void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted
this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=  webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
```

**Full Snippet**

*Html*

```
 <form method="post" >
      <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="3" id="a3">
      <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="2" id="a2">
      <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="1" id="a1">
      <input value="Next"  type="submit" onclick="alert('Next Button Submitted')">
  </form>
```

*Form1.cs*

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string url = @"https://localhost:5001/Home/Index";
    webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=  webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

}

private async void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    var radioBoxValue = "1";
    var submitButtonValue = "Next";

    //Click Radio Box
    var findRadioBox = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").OfType<HtmlElement>()
                .Where(html => html.GetAttribute("type").Equals("radio") && html.GetAttribute("value").Equals(radioBoxValue)).FirstOrDefault();
    findRadioBox.InvokeMember("Click");

    //Click Button
     var findsubmitButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").OfType<HtmlElement>()
                .Where(html => html.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit") && html.GetAttribute("value").Equals(submitButtonValue)).FirstOrDefault();
    findsubmitButton.InvokeMember("Click");

    //Unsubscribing from the document completed event, there are times when you will run into situations where documentcompelted will fire multiple times
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're asking, you could just set the value of radio button to be default to checked and when the document is ready to submit such form

```
<form id="frmSb" name="frmSb" method="post" onsubmit="alert('submitted')">
   <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="3" id="a3">
   <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="2" id="a2" checked>
   <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="1" id="a1" >
   <input id="submitBtn" value="Next" type="submit">
</form>

//This to the end of file
<script>    
document.getElementById("frmSb").submit();
</script>
```

Comment: i dont have access to edit the html code on the website